# Designing a multi-module, cross-team web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, maf

**Background**

We're redesigning an internal web application (ASP.NET MVC3), with the goal of easing development and especially deployment. The application is a back office web, to which several teams develop modules. The last few years, this has been done working in the same project, and then doing a full release of "everything" whenever anyone needed to release. Unsurprisingly, this hasn't worked that well. We are now in a situation where half a dozen teams want to release modules, on different schedules, which makes the situation unbearable.

What we would like to accomplish:

1. Each team develops their own separate modules, which are then loaded into the framework.
2. Such modules should be deployable without redeploying the base application, or any other modules.
3. Modules need to be able to provide partial views to other modules

**The problem**

We have made a proof-of-concept fulfilling all three requirements. Intermodule communication is handled using DI containers. This works quite well - with one caveat. When modules have different versions of some dependency, we get a version mismatch. If we want to avoid going back what we have and forcing everyone to re-deploy every time someone updates some dependency, we need to be able to load several versions of dependencies.

From what I understand, this will require us to load modules into separate AppDomains. This seems to raise a number of issues. Firstly, a number of discussions seem to say that this works very poorly with IIS/ASP.NET with regards to ThreadStatic variables etc. Secondly, we will need to do marshalling between the domains, which seems non-trivial and will add a lot of complexity. Thirdly, intermodule communication also looks to become painful.

I've looked briefly at MAF, which at least seems to give some framework support for this type of architecture, but it also looks decidedly complicated... Are there better alternatives, either some supporting framework, or design?

Comment: It looks like time has come to break this horror into separate applications. Modules work well if they all strictly follow well established rules. If each team decides to use whatever framework and version he wants that your application is jeopardized.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: It's not so bad as "whatever framework and version". But consider the scenario where some shared library is updated with a new feature. It is not realistic that because of an unrelated feature addition we would need to recompile, retest and redeploy some fifty units of code. Breaking it up is of course one alternative, but I've failed to see a way to do that without impacting the user experience. Allowing cross-application partial views is also going to be problematic, I think.

Comment: And you think that you can just plug a new module and not retest the entire application??? This module is loaded into the same domain as the host application and could break it in millions of places that you might never expect. Hopefully you already have automated tests that you could run to validate that there's no regression when you ship something new.

Comment: Maybe think about modularising the UI so that separate portions of the screen are served from different domains. Each team can be responsible for their own domain and make changes without affecting the others. The app itself would be 'thin' as it would have no content of its own, it would just be composed of distinct domain services that are brought together in a single interface.